# Does Apache Pig have any limitations on the input data size?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

When working with TeraBytes of data, and for a typical data filtering problem, is Apache PIG the right choice? Or is it better to have a custom MapReduce code doing the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache PIG does not serve as a storage layer. PIG is a scripting language that simplifies creation of the code that can run on Hadoop. PIG script is compiled into a set of Hadoop MapReduce jobs that are submitted to the Hadoop and which run in the same way as any other MapReduce Job.

Hadoop does the data storage and not PIG.

To answer your question: No, there are no limitations on the size of the input data. As long as the input data can be parsed by PIG load functions and it is splittable by the Hadoop InputFormats.

PIG scripts are easier and faster to write than standard Java Hadoop jobs and PIG has lot of clever optimizations like multiquery execution, which can make your complex queries execute quicker.

Comment: Yeah exactly what I was in need to know - "there are no limitations on the size of the input data". Shall that be taken for granted? Rest of it is fine, I have ample storage space on my HDFS and my files can be easily recognized by the InputFormats.

Comment: You are limited only your hardware, network, memory, cores, blades. Not by the Apache PIG. You could try using SequenceFiles compressed with LZO by BLOCK. PIG does not do it by default, but there is some in the Piggy Bank.